# Estimating the reddening of a star?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, stars, galaxies, milky-way

I'm stuck on a question concerning how to estimate the reddening of a star. The question is:

"A star near the Galactic plane has observed apparent magnitudes in the blue and visual bands
of $B = 15.48$, $V = 14.58$.

Comparison of a spectrum of the star to a library of local star spectra
indicates that it has absolute magnitudes $M_B = 3.20$, and $M_V = 2.70$.

Given that the reddening
ratio for interstellar dust is $A_V /E_{B − V} = 3.0$, estimate (i) the reddening of the star, (ii) the
V-band extinction in magnitudes, and (iii) the distance to the star in parsecs."

---

I can see how to do both parts (ii) and (iii) but I am stuck on the first part. I assume in estimating the reddening I would need to calculate the colour excess

$E_{B-V}=(B-V)-(B-V)_{intrinsic}=A_B-A_V$,

with $A_{B(V)}=B(V)-B(V)_{intrinsic}$.

So I would need the intrinsic $B$ and $V$ values, which aren't given in the question or rubric and I don't know how to obtain these. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The intrinsic B and V values *are* given in the question.

Comment: @RobJeffries are the intrinsic values just the absolute magnitudes?

Comment: The absolute magnitudes are the magnitudes the stars would have if they were 10pc away and take no account of extinction.